# Why does awk field seperater not work with \s?

Tags: awk, field

I run a command like this:

```
echo "aaa bbb  ccc    dddd" | awk -F "\\s+" '{print $1,$2}'
```

Expected output is `aaa bbb`.

But actually the field seperater does not work!

Why? Can please anybody help?

Comment: What about this `echo "aaa bbb  ccc    dddd" | awk '{print $1,$2}'` ?

Comment: It did work, but I meet some issue which needs set field seperator with regular expression, so I want to find out why \s cannot work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because awk treats the Field seperator value `\\s` as plain `s` . You need to escape it one more time so that it would tell to the awk that it isn't a plain `s`, it's a special meta character which matches all the whitespaces.

```
$ echo "aaa bbb  ccc    dddd" | awk -F "\\\s+" '{print $1,$2}'
aaa bbb
```

Comment: I installed mawk, and still did not get expected output. :(

Comment: try `echo "aaa bbb  ccc    dddd" | awk -v FS="\\\s+" '{print $1,$2}'`

Comment: i don't know why it doesn't work for you. But it works for me. My awk version is `GNU Awk 4.0.1`

Comment: Still not work, maybe it's issue of my environment, thank you all the same. My version is GNU Awk 3.1.5.

Comment: in the previous versions, it won't consider `\s` as space char. This `echo "aaa bbb ccc dddd" | awk -F" +" '{print $1,$2}'` should work for your version.

Comment: My version is GNU Awk 3.1.5, I will upgrade and check it later. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to adjust the field separator in this case, as the default one does exactly what you want:

```
echo "aaa bbb  ccc    dddd" | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

Will give you the desired output.

The `\s` character class is only available in some newer versions of awk. If you ever find that you need it in another context, you may be able to use the POSIX `[[:space:]]` character class. Alternatively, if you only want to match one or more space () characters, you can use `+` (that's a single space followed by a plus sign).